# How to Implement functions from type signatures?

Tags: function, haskell, types, functional-programming, implementation

I have the following two type signatures in Haskell:

```
foo :: (a -> (a,b)) -> a -> [b]

bar :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> c
```

I want to write a concrete implementation of these two functions but I'm really struggling to understand where to start.

I understand that `foo` takes a function `(a -> (a,b))` and returns `a` and a list containing `b`.

And `bar` takes a function `(b -> c)` which returns a function `(a -> b -> c)` which finally returns `a` and `c`.

Can anyone show me an example of a concrete implementation?

How do I know where to start with something like this and what goes on the left side of the definition?

Answer (score 5):

You have some misunderstandings there:

> I understand that `foo` takes a function `(a -> (a,b))` and returns `a` and a list containing `b`.

No, it doesn't return `a`. It expects it as another argument, in addition to that function.

> And `bar` takes a function `(b -> c)` which returns a function `(a -> b -> c)` which finally returns `a` and `c`.

Same here. Given `g :: a -> b`, `bar` returns a function `bar g :: (a -> b -> c) -> a -> c`. This function, in turn, given a function `h :: (a -> b -> c)`, returns a function of type `a -> c`. And so it goes.

---

It's just like playing with pieces of a puzzle:

```
foo :: (a -> (a,b)) -> a -> [b]
--   g   :: a -> (a,b)
--     x :: a
--   g x ::      (a,b)
foo g x = [b]  where
  (a,b) = g x

bar :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> c
--   g   :: a -> b
--     x :: a
--   g x ::      b
--   h   :: a -> b -> c
--   h x ::      b -> c
--   h x (g x)     :: c
bar g h x = c  where
  c = ....
```

There's not much free choice for us here. Although, there are more ways to get more values of type `b`, for `foo`. Instead of ignoring that `a` in `(a,b) = g x`, we can use it in more applications of `g`, so there actually are many more possibilities there, like

```
foo2 :: (a -> (a,b)) -> a -> [b]
foo2 g x = [b1,b2]  where
  (a1,b1) = g x
  (a2,b2) = g a1
```

and many more. Still, the types guide the possible implementations. `foo` can even make use of `foo` in its implementation, according to the types:

```
foo3 :: (a -> (a,b)) -> a -> [b]
foo3 g x = b : bs  where
  (a,b) = g x
  bs = ...
```

So now, with this implementation, the previous two become its special cases: `foo g x === take 1 (foo3 g x)` and `foo2 g x === take 2 (foo3 g x)`. Having the most general definition is probably best.

Comment: Didn't you miss the "obvious"/most likely actual implementation of `foo`, specifically `foo g x = b:foo g a where (a,b) = g x`?

Comment: that's actually equivalent to what I intended with the last one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @will-nes's answer, it will be useful to treat (->) as a right-associative infix operator. So something like `f: a -> b -> c` is the same as `f: a -> (b -> c)`. So this is saying `f` is a function that takes a value of type `a` and returns you a value of type `b -> c`, which is, another function, one that takes a value of type `b` and returns you a value of type `c`.

So the types in your example can be re-written as follows

```
foo :: (a -> (a,b)) -> (a -> [b])

bar :: (a -> b) -> ((a -> (b -> c)) -> (a -> c))
```

Similarly, you can think of arguments to a function in pieces as well, as being left-associative (like + and -), though there's no explicit operator in this case. `foo a b c d e` is the same as `((((foo a) b) c) d) e`. For example, let's say we have a function `f: Int -> Int -> Int` (which is the same as `f: Int -> (Int -> Int)`). You don't have to provide both arguments at once. So you can write `g = f 1`, which has the type `(Int -> Int)`. And then you can provide an argument to `g`, like `g 2`, which has the type `Int`. `f 1 2` and `let g = f 1 in g 2` are more or less the same. Here's a more concrete example of how this works:

```
Prelude> f = (+)
Prelude> g = f 1
Prelude> g 2
3
Prelude> :t f
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
Prelude> :t g
g :: Num a => a -> a
Prelude> :t g 2
g 2 :: Num a => a
```

In @will-nes's sample implementation examples, he defines the functions with all of the arguments up front, but you don't have to think of them that way. Just think of `f: a -> b -> c` as taking a value of type `a` and returning another function. While most of the methods you encounter will use all of their arguments up-front, there might be cases in which you don't want to do that. Here's an example:

```
veryExpensive :: A -> B

unstagedFun :: A -> (B -> C) -> C
unstagedFun a f = f (veryExpensive a)

stagedFun :: A -> (B -> C) -> C
stagedFun a = let b = veryExpensive a in \f -> f b
```

(You can also rewrite the latter as `let b = veryExpensive a in ($ b)`)

Of course, with compiler optimizations, I wouldn't be surprised if the unstaged version staged automatically, but hopefully this offers some motivation for thinking of functions as not having multiple arguments, but rather, as a single argument, but they may return other functions that may themselves return functions (but also only take a single argument).